# Making sure singleton properties aren't accessible via other instance

Tags: ios, swift

I have a singleton class:

```
final class NotificationSingleton : NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = NotificationSingleton()
    var aProperty: String!
    var anotherProperty: Int!
}
```

How can I make sure that `aProperty` and `anotherProperty` are only accessible through the `sharedInstance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make the initializer private
thus no other instances can be created

```
private override init() {}
```

Comment: How can this be achieved in objective c?

Comment: i have no idea on that

Comment: Dirty solution:
```- (id)init {
    @throw @"Nah"; // this prevents [Object new] call
}

- (id)initWithStuff:(bool)x {
    return self = [super init]; // use this in instance generator
}```

Answer (score 0):

You could use failable initializers to prevent the creation of additional `NotificationSingleton` instances once your `sharedInstance` has been set.

I suspect this sort of defensive programming will actually make the class hostile to use by other developers in the future, difficult to test, and that there's probably a cleaner solution available which doesn't rely on singletons as globals but there you go.